# c# why can't a nullable int be assigned null as a value

Tags: c#, nullable

Explain why a nullable int can't be assigned the value of null e.g

```
int? accom = (accomStr == "noval" ? null  : Convert.ToInt32(accomStr));
```

What's wrong with that code?

Comment: You can assign null value to NullableInt you only need to use below syntax if val is your nullableint variable than val=new NullableInt(true);

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The problem isn't that null cannot be assigned to an int?. The problem is that both values returned by the ternary operator must be the same type, or one must be implicitly convertible to the other. In this case, null cannot be implicitly converted to int nor vice-versus, so an explict cast is necessary. Try this instead:

```
int? accom = (accomStr == "noval" ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(accomStr));
```

Comment: It's interesting - you don't actually need the cast for Convert.ToInt32...

Comment: It's because System.Int32 != System.Nullable<Int32>

Comment: Why does long? work without the cast?

Comment: As Joe R said, my cast on the Convert.ToInt32() was not necessary. There is an implicit cast from int to int?. The cast on the null is necessary regardless of whether you use int? or long?. The other options is to cast only the Convert.ToInt32() to an int? or long? (as suggested by Will Dean) as this will make the null convertible to the nullable type. The issue is that there isn't an implicit cast from <null> => int or from int => <null>.

Comment: i would prefer default(int?) over (int?)null;

Comment: I just didn't realize, I had to convert null ...

Comment: `'null's` also need to be casted.. : )

Comment: I would prefer not to cast null because it is confusing to read. Instead of relying on implicit casting for the integer value, make it explicit.   int? result = (condition) ? null: (int?)myInt;

Answer (score 47):

What Harry S says is exactly right, but

```
int? accom = (accomStr == "noval" ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(accomStr));
```

would also do the trick.  (We Resharper users can always spot each other in crowds...)

Comment: Now that is nice, that's just a subtle difference but sooo simple! Would +2 if I could (despite it being such a little thing) =)

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use

```
int? accom = (accomStr == "noval" ? Convert.DBNull : Convert.ToInt32(accomStr);
```

I like this one most.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  It should give the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 1):

Similarly I did for long:

```
myLongVariable = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbLong.SelectedItem.Value)) ? Convert.ToInt64(cbLong.SelectedItem.Value) : (long?)null;
```